# Dynamic background colour and child element colour inheritance

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page where the background colour can be set dynamically. In some instances I have child divs I would like to use background-color:inherit to keep them the same colour as the body.

What I find is that when the body background colour is changed, the inherited colours aren't consistently cascaded. It appears to be ok in Firefox but not in Chrome or IE.

In firefox it consistently changes both elements. In chrome and IE the results seem varied, but if you click on the colour the background already is (e.g. everything is blue, click on the "blue" button) and then another colour, it seems to consistently break.

(I do realise the inherited colour isn't needed in this example, however I'm just trying to demo the issue in as little code as possible.)

http://jsfiddle.net/48HBe/2/

If this were one browser only then I would suspect this was a possible browser issue, but as it seems to affect Chrome and IE I'm wondering if I'm expecting something unreasonable from the browser's rendering and whether I should be using an alternative approach?

Comment: On chrome 20.0.1132.43 it seems it's working fine

Comment: @F.Calderan Also on Chrome 20.0.1132.43 - if you click the blue button first, and then another colour, does it definitely keep up to date?

Comment: @Timbo it works perfectly to me (I'm using Chrome on MacOs 10.6.8) ... anyway take a look at my answer

Comment: Opera 12 displays also everything as expected...

Comment: @F.Calderan Ah I'm on win 7 - slightly surprised the issue would be platform specific but guess it could come down to under-the-bonnet rendering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine in Chrome, anyway if the problem is related to IE, I would try a different approach. Instead of changing a single css property, just try to change the class name of `body` element, like in this example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/48HBe/3/

the css thus becomes

```
body, body.blue { background-color:blue; }
body.green { background-color:green; }
body.red { background-color:red; }
```

and the js code is simply

```
...
var b = document.body;
$("#RedButton").click(function()   { b.className = 'red';   });                  
$("#GreenButton").click(function() { b.className = 'green'; });                  
$("#BlueButton").click(function()  { b.className = 'blue';  });
```

doing so you have a better separation between logic and presentation and you could change more style properties inside the css (and not inside js code)

Comment: Thanks - this is a good workaround for the issue as demonstrated (and certainly seems to work ok in both the browsers I was having issues with). In the production code I'm actually selecting the colour from a colour picker control so I don't have the option of specifying class names. However the fact that your solution works is encouraging that there's not a fundamental issue with cascading the colours. I might see if I can find a similar alternative approach...

Comment: It seems the class change does "encourage" cascading of updated styles where style attribute changes aren't reliable. I used a (meaningless) class change to get the required results - thanks for your input. http://jsfiddle.net/48HBe/5/

Answer (score 0):

I removed `background-color:inherit;` and it did the work.

Comment: As per my disclaimer by my link in the question, the example is over-simplified to demonstrate my problem, normally there would be other elements that would mean the background colour would have to be set.